# How to force SQL Server 2008 to not change AUTOINC_NEXT value when IDENTITY_INSERT is ON?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, identity, auto-increment, seed

I got question about IDENTITY_INSERT. When you change it to ON, SQL Server automatically changes AUTOINC_NEXT value to the last inserted value as identity.

So if you got only one row with ID = 1 and insert row with ID = 100 while IDENTITY_INSERT is ON then next inserting row will have ID = 101. I'd like it to be 2 without need to reseed.

Such behaviour already exists in SQL Server Compact 3.5. Is it possible to force SQL Server 2008 to not change AUTOINC_NEXT value while doing insert with IDENTITY_INSERT = ON ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to prevent this behavior - after all, it's a prudent thing to do, anyway! If you've already set a value `x` (whatever that value might be), you shouldn't leave your seed value lower than `x` since otherwise, you're bound to run into getting a value in your IDENTITY column that's already there - not a good place to be!

But if you must, you can re-seed your IDENTITY column after you're done with your inserts using:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('YourTableName', RESEED, 300);
```

where you can set any arbitrary value as your new seed value (here: 300). Of course, you need to be extra careful not to create any duplicates by setting the reseed value too low.

Comment: Thing is I'll set unique range of id's for every user - with bigint it should be easily achievable. What I wanted to do is to reserve lower parts of id's for central db to which others will synchronize.When I'll want to write data from mobile db to central I need to insert with identity_insert on but that makes current identity value set to id of last inserted row which is bad. I would have to reseed after every insert to keep consistency. Solution would be to reserve last part of number for central and then current identity value won't change back to lower value.

Comment: Built-in replication is not what I look for because when you make change of filter in publisher you need to have all clients synchronized already otherwise new data won't go up from mobile to central db. Maybe there's some way to solve this so you won't lose data from mobile ?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you do a reseed and your identity column is also a primary key, when you get back to the originally inserted value when IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON was set you will get a PK violation. Another thing to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that? In the first place, there should be almost no occasions where you set identity insert to ON in a production system. And what difference would it make if you skip some? You can't count on identities not skipping in any event since it will skip if you do a rollback.